# Maximum FlashVars length IE8?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, internet-explorer, flashvars

Is there some kind of maximum length for a flashvars string when using swfobject and IE8?

I'm passing a Facebook session object into Flash via FlashVars, and in FF and Chrome this works fine.  In IE howver, it seems that only a certain amount of data is passed, and the string is cut off at an arbitrary point.  This results in Flash incorrectly parsing the incoming data.

The PHP that gets the session object:

```
function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
    $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
    $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);
    return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
    $session = json_encode(parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'],'<<APP SECRET>>'));
} else {
    $session = '';
}

$lang = 'UK';
```

Assembling the FlashVars:

```
var flashvars = {
    popUpsAllowed:true,
    deployPath:"<<PATH>>",
    fb_type:"popup", 
    fb_environment:"iframe",
    fb_app_id:"<<APP ID>>",
    fb_redirect:"<<REDIRECT URL>>",
    session:'<?php echo $session; ?>',
    lang:'<?php echo $lang; ?>',
    nobreak:null }
```

So now in Flash running in IE attempting to access `stage.loaderInfo.parameters.session` throws a null object error, but works fine in FF.

Am I going to have to resort to requesting the session through externalInterface to avoid overloading the FlashVars?

**EDIT:** So taking the session var away and requesting it later through ExternalInterface works, but I'd like to know whether it's IE or the ActiveX plugin that's at fault here.

The session data looks like this (some numeric characters changed):

```
{"algorithm":"HMAC-SHA256","expires":1304334000,"issued_at":1304327676,"oauth_token":"100076334000000|0.kNHAz0AST_cq0jo7WLWldQ__.0000.0004334000.1-000000000|UIy7h_0NFYByedFUGDkxOntP8Sg","user":{"country":"gb","locale":"en_GB","age":{"min":21}},"user_id":"000000000"}
```

**Edit2:*** So I'm an idiot, when you view code in the IE Dev Tool it does crop off loads, but copying an element's inner html into a text editor lets you see the whole thing. So the session string doesn't seem to be corrupted, but it's still not getting into flash correctly, `loaderInfo.parameters.session` exists but is null, and `loaderInfo.parameters.lang` is not defined.

This is the actual browser output of the FlashVars:

```
var flashvars = {
    popUpsAllowed:true,
    deployPath:"http://www.mydomain.com",
    fb_type:"popup",
    fb_environment:"iframe",
    fb_app_id:"00000000000000000000000000000000",
    fb_redirect:"http://apps.facebook.com/myApp/iframe_popup.php",
    session:'{"algorithm":"HMAC-SHA256","expires":1304416800,"issued_at":1304412506,"oauth_token":"000176004606000|2.01KBxkU8muE0AeIQSNlXLg__.3000.1304400800.0-500428000|_KXAwxTxzGSmasOu0KlNFHQ0d7A","user":{"country":"gb","locale":"en_GB","age":{"min":21}},"user_id":"000000000"}',
    lang:'UK',
    nobreak:null}
```

Comment: Another thing look at the rendered HTML and see what is being assigned to session.

Comment: I looked in the IE dev tool, and it shows part of the session string, but just stops at a certain length. It almost looks like the dev tool is just not showing the complete line, but then session shows as the last parameter of loaderInfo.parameters when it should be lang, and session is null, which suggests that IE is cropping the line.  I don't think escaping will help because I now use a callback in Flash to set the data, and it passes through that unescaped in IE with no problem.

Comment: Take a good look at the session string. Does it have any non-alpha-numeric characters?

Comment: Can you post the session string?

Comment: It looks perfectly OK to me.  Posted it in the question.

Comment: Sorry I was't specific enough can you post the exact line of string that is here  session:'<?php echo $session; ?>' as it is on the browser side.

Comment: Question updated. So the javascript appears fine in IE too, but this doesn't all get passed into Flash for some reason.

Comment: Yeah it looks like you need to urlencode it. Pipes and colons I think are what your problem is. Flashvars get past to the swf on the query string. The IE dev tool bar was breaking because it couldn't render the pipe or colon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to urlencode it. Pipes and colons I think are what your problem is. Flashvars get past to the swf on the query string. The IE dev tool bar was breaking because it couldn't render the pipe or colon.

Answer (score 2):

All browsers will support string sizes of up to 64KB (65535 bytes) in length. FlashVars must be assigned in both the OBJECT and EMBED tags in order to work on all browsers. Check out Adobe's take on FlashVars at [Using FlashVars to pass variables to a SWF](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html).

Comment: See, that's the thing here. The total length is nowhere near 64KB, and using swfobject ensures the flashvars are correctly placed.  When tracing the loaderInfo.parameters object the vars before session are populated correctly and the var after session doesn't appear.